# How can I run a DC fan and ultrasonic fogger on one cord?

Tags: electrical, wiring, humidifier

I want to build a humidifier for our tree frog terrarium by putting a ultrasonic fogger in a container of water and then attaching a computer fan on the lid. I'd like to combine the power for both the fan and the fogger so there is just one plug that goes in the wall.

Any ideas how to combine the fogger and fan so together there is only 1 power cord?

Comment: Are you asking how to rewire things? That would probably be off-topic for DIYSE. Obviously the PC fan requires low-level DC voltage. How are you supplying that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about DIYSE, didn't know about it! And the reason for not using the extension cord is because i'd rather have 1 cord come out of the terrarium instead of 2. But, yes in a pinch, I could use an extension cord, just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment after thinking through the PC fan thing. See the current version.

Comment: Good question, I figured probably add a 12v adapter to it?

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably want to delete this and hit up http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only moments ago, I was researching these devices, both the fans and the ultrasonic foggers. The foggers are 24vdc and your choice of fans should be based on that figure. I have a number of 24vdc muffin fans, about 50mm diameter which were removed from discarded workstation computers, but that may not help you, other than to indicate that you should be able to find a fan of this voltage. You'll be cutting into either the wiring at the power supply lead or into the wiring at the ultrasonic unit, in order to join them, but other than that, it should be no serious challenge. The power supply for the ultrasonic humidifier should not be rated to be maxing out when using the unit, so there may be enough "suplus power" to run the fan. That's only item about which you should be cautious.

A quick search on eBay shows dozens of low priced 24v computer-type fans and an equally large number of low cost ultrasonic devices.